# How to set all timezone variables in _JAVA_OPTIONS

Tags: java, environment-variables

I am setting timezone in environment variables _JAVA_OPTIONS as `-Duser.timezone=GMT`

If I have to add values to other variables of timezone how should I include it in _JAVA_OPTIONS?

I want to add a value for dstSavings.

```
id=GMT,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=false,startYear=0,startMode=0,startMonth=0,startDay=0,startDayOfWeek=0,startTime=0,startTimeMode=0,endMode=0,endMonth=0,endDay=0,endDayOfWeek=0,endTime=0,endTimeMode=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a long string as environement value.

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dsome=value -Dsomething.else=someothervalue .."
```

So yours could be..

```
 _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Duser.timezone=GMT  -DdstSavings=id=GMT,offset=0,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=false,startYear=0,startMode=0,startMonth=0,startDay=0,startDayOfWeek=0,startTime=0,startTimeMode=0,endMode=0,endMonth=0,endDay=0,endDayOfWeek=0,endTime=0,endTimeMode=0"
```